# Best way to do init without repeating code?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, class

Each view class has multiple init methods - ones already included as part of UIView, and then additional ones - and each of them set up the same elements in the same way. I therefore usually have them all running a `[self initialSetup];` method, which includes the setting up of all of these elements.

The problem i've ran into is that if a subclass also has an initialSetup method, it would override the superclass initialSetup method, and thus the superclass would have to have the method be public in order to still function. This causes problems with organisation, as the method should never be called other than from init, so has no reason to be public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit upon a problem that there's no perfect fix for. What you'd ideally have is a method that can't be subclassed in the normal sense, that's accessible only to instances of that exact type of class.

Where this is a risk, the normal practice seems to be to incorporate the class name into the setup method. So instead of `initialSetup` you'd have something like `myViewSubclassInitialSetup`.

You can also add something like this at the top of your method:

```
NSAssert([self isMemberOfClass:[ThisClass class]], 
             @"IniitalSetup called by sub- or superclass")
```

Then your debug builds will raise an exception if a subclass or superclass ends up calling your init method. That'll give you a place for a breakpoint and a stacktrace that should allow you to find the problem very quickly.

It won't add any code to your release builds.

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of `initialSetup` to something like `initialSetupClassName` - subclasses, even if they accidentally used the same pattern, would not use the same name as they had a different class name.

You can also use an "_" prefix for private methods you would rather not be called, but the subclasser may do that also.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are missing a designated initializer. Designate one initializer as the official one that actually performs the setup, and have all the others just call that with some degree of customization. Usually the designated initializer will be the one with the most detail — for example, if you have `init`, `initWithName:`, `initWithName:age:` and `initAsFiveYearOldNamed:`, the designated initializer will be `initWithName:age:` and the other initializers would just call that method with the arguments filled in appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly `Objective C` doesn't provide a way to achieve that in a "clean" way. The ideal solution would be a protected method. But that's not possible in `Objective C`

Apple had this problem, when they were creating the `UIGestureRecognizer`. There were some methods they really didn't want to get called by somebody, but which had to be overwritten by subclasses. The way they chose to deal with this, was to create a seperate header file (`UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h`), that contains a category to the original `UIGestureRecognizer` with those "protected" methods. The additional header is only to be imported by subclasses (i.e. for subclassing purposes). See [UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for some details.

Of course that doesn't prevent anybody from misusing the additional header file, but at least it clearly states your intention and keeps your code well structured. Also you won't be "bothered" by autocompletion for the additional methods, when just using the class.

Personally I only use an additional header, if it is extremely important that nobody calls it directly. In most cases I think it's ok to use public methods and make a note for what it's inteded. The iOS Framework also has many of these cases. F.e. many methods of `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` etc.